# Floating Point: are round(x-y) and -round(y-x) equal?

Tags: computer-science, floating-point

I think they should intuitively be equal. But I don't know how to show it. And I can't find a counter example to it either to disprove it.

Comment: Try stack exchange: stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you round half-odd-integers.  If you use the "round half up" rule, $\text{round}(1/2) = 1$ but $\text{round}(-1/2) = 0$.

Comment: Yes thank you I just realized this! Also works for 1.25 and -1.25, 1.25 rounds up to 1.3 and -1.25 rounds up to -1.2

Comment: On the other hand, IEEE floating pointe also defines a "balanced rounding" mode where half-integers round to their _even_ neighbor. This is invariant under negation.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is not the same. Choose $x=1$ and $y=0.5$, for example.

But if the difference is not of the form $n+0.5$ with integer $n$, the two expressions give the same value.

Comment: In IEEE 754 arithmetic there are "directed rounding modes" (towards $+\infty$ or towards $-\infty$) for which the answers, unless integral, are  guaranteed to be different.